# How can I use play library in Python?

Tags: python, import, flappy-bird-clone

I wanted to do a Flappy bird kind of project and I needed to import play library.

I use VS Code and when I click on the "play" wiriting it converts to "Playsound". It doesn't work and I use MacBook. If you can help me I would be glad... Thanks in advance :)

```
import play
import random

bird = play.new_image(image ="bird.png",x=-100,size=9)
obstacle_1 = play.new_box(x = 440,y = 300 ,height = 350,width =80,color = "blue",border_width= 5,border_color="black")
obstacle_2 = play.new_box(x = 440,y = -300,height = 550,width =80,color = "blue",border_width= 5,border_color="black")
bird.start_physics(stable = True , can_move= True , obeys_gravity= True,bounciness = 0.5)
point = 0
scor = play.new_text(words = str(point),x = 350,y = 250)
@play.repeat_forever
def jump():
    global point
    scor.words = str(puan)
    if play.key_is_pressed("w","W"):
        bird.physics.y_speed = 30
    if obstacle_1.x > -450:
        obstacle_1.x -= 5
        obstacle_2.x -= 5
    else :
        obstacle_1.x = 440
        obstacle_2.x = 440
        randomnumber = random.randint(0,940)
        obstacle_1.height = 940-randomnnumber
        obstacle_2.height = randomnumber
    if obstacle_1.x == -100:
        point += 1
    if bird.is_touching(obstacle_1) or bird.is_touching(obstacle_2):
        point = 0
        obstacle_1.x = 440
        obstacle_2.x = 440
play.start_program()
```

Comment: what do you mean by "it doesn't work"? is an exception thrown? have you installed `pygame`? it seems is a pre-requirement...

Comment: I meant to say I'm not able to use the play module, even I installed pygame.

Comment: also I have installed pygame